# How can I solve Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':image_picker_android:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath problem

Tags: flutter, build, lintvitalrelease

When I tries to run the application, It's works fine.
But when I build signed apk,
There was an error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':image_picker_android:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /home/pappuraj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.68/46a080368d38b428d237a59458f9bc915222894d/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar.
> > Failed to transform '/home/pappuraj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.68/46a080368d38b428d237a59458f9bc915222894d/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 59. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Suggestions:
> - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
> - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           14.2s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem adding this section.

I added this code in the android section of app level build file.

```
  lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        disable "Instantiatable"
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
```

[image]